# Storing UIView with children

Tags: swift, for-loop, uiview

Im working on a 2x2 grid with everyone of them having a UIView and a child label with text and background color.

I generate the UIView with a for loop like this:

```
// Generatin answer cube buttons
        for var i = 0; i < cubeCount; i++
        {
            // two answers case
            if(cubeCount < 3)
            {
                var btn = button(xpos, y: ypos, width: screenWidth, height: (screenHeight * 2));
                var lbl = labelis("\(i)", btn: btn)
                btn.addSubview(lbl)

                xpos = xpos + (screenWidth + 10);
                self.view.addSubview(btn);
            }
            // 3+ answers case
            else
            {
                var btn = button(xpos, y: ypos, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight);
                var lbl = labelis("\(i)", btn: btn)
                btn.addSubview(lbl)

                xpos = xpos + (screenWidth + 10)
                self.view.addSubview(btn)

                // change row in case of more than 2 answers
                if(i == 1)
                {
                    xpos = 20
                    ypos = ypos + (screenHeight + 10)
                }
            }
```

I also have a tapGesture function letting me know when I click on one of the  answer cube.

My problem here is that, when clicking on one of the cube, I would like to access all the cubes and change their label's background color.

I though about storing the UIView into an array so I could act on them from the tapGesture function, but I don't see how I could make this work.

I though that maybe someone could guide me through the way of dealing with this.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a solution to my problem so I answer my own question for people who might look into this in the future:

I've created an array:

```
var answerData:[UIView] = [];
```

and added my UIView along the way for those I wanted to keep stored

```
var uiviewvariable = UIView()    
answerData.append(uiviewVariable)
```

then, on my tapGesture function, when the user tap one of the view, I can call for the array and use act on the UIViews

```
// Accessing stored UIView
        for(var i = 0; i < answerData.count; i++){

            // Accessing subviews
            for subview in answerData[i].subviews as [UIView]
            {
                if subview.tag == 0
                {
                    if let label = subview as? UILabel {
                        // do something with label inside the views
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
```

for some reason I use something similar than Abdullah's answer for selecting my labels but I didn't managed to make his snippet work.

Answer (score 0):

In the click handler of cube button try following code:

```
for subview in view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let cubeButton = subview as? button {
        //Do something with this cubeButton here.
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but this is only for the clicked button? I looking to act on all generated uiviews.

Comment: This will iterate through all the subviews of self.view and if found to be of type button will enter the if condition.

Comment: it triggers error: reauire "in" 

sorry Im quite new to swift...

isn't possible to build up a UIView, add components,  store it in an array and then use the data inside this array ? This is what I add in mind.
Scanning for all components seems a bit intensive no?

Comment: I have changed the code to resolve error. You could store all the views you create in an array and use them as you wish. I just gave you solution that will save you from declaring array and adding views to it. Storing views in separate array may cause problem later on if you forgot to add views to this array.

Comment: didn't manage to make this works... however I went for the array solution and it works pretty well.